# Reactjs TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually I have just started learning react. I'm taking tutorials from websites. but when I compiled my this code in command line it says "Compiled Successfully" but when I open the browser it says

> "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Actually I don't know how to fix this issue. But due to this error I'm unable to continue my course.

```
import React, {component} from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';

class App extends component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
        robots: robots,
        searchfield: ''     
        }
    }
    onSearchChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
    render () {
    return (
        <div className='tc'>
        <h1> RoboFriends </h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
        <CardList robots ={this.state.robots}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
 }  

export default App;
```

Comment: React works with Capital letters. So it's 'extends Component' not 'extends component'

Comment: Same thing with the import, component should be Component.

Answer (score 2):

`React` uses `PascalCase` naming for components (class),

```
import React, {component} from 'react';
```

here `component` should be `Component`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
```

Or you have another way,

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
```

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize the word "component"

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component
```